# Deleting Item from ListView

Tags: android, listview

I want to create an edit button and a listview with some list items.

When the button is pressed, listitem should be deleted.

How can I do it ? Please try to write code if possible.

Comment: you need to delete the value from the arraylist you have used. and the use notifydatasetchanged method for the adapter u have used. cause thenm only the change will reflect

Comment: Use this library: https://github.com/baoyongzhang/SwipeMenuListView

Answer (score 0):

`OnClick` of **Edit Button**, you will have to update your data source, which you are passing to the list `adapter`. And then call `adapter.notifyDatasetChanged()`.

```
adapter = new CustomListAdapter(getActivity(), adapter,dataList);
```

You will have to update this `dataList` and call `adapter.notifyDatasetChanged()` on button Click.